# Creating a global UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create an application with a feature similar to facebook's chat bubbles.

When the user navigates to a certain page (InCallViewController), they can connect to another person via video chat. When they navigate out of this page after connecting, I would like the video view to stay floating on the screen, but allow them to do what ever they want to do in the app.

In order to do this, I have made an InCallViewController class, which will allow the user to connect with the other person. Once connected, the video is displayed in a view. This view is movable (similar to facebook's chat bubbles) and displays the video chat perfectly, however when I exit the page and go to another page (AccountViewController) in the app, I am unable to keep this view on the screen. I have tried many things, including setting this view as a subview in the later pages. However when I do this, the subview is not displayed.

MyAccountView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [super viewDidLoad];

    InCallViewController *inCallViewController = [[InCallViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InCallViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:inCallViewController.previewView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:inCallViewController.previewView];

    (Do some other set up stuff)

}
```

InCallViewController.h

```
@interface InCallViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> 
{

    CGPoint currentTouch;
    NSArray *viewArray;
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *previewVideoView;
```

The previewView is a UIView in the InCallViewController class. This is hooked up in the IB, and works perfectly when in the InCallController class. The problem is, it won't show up when adding it as a subview in another class. I am wondering what I am doing wrong, or if there is a better way to keep the "previewView" remaining on the screen after I exit InCallViewController.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should consider implementing a container viewController. Since iOS6 and xcode 4.5 this has been made pretty straightforward.
The containing viewController can be handling your previewViews which are overlayed over whatever viewController is currently contained in it.
You can compare what you want to achieve with what Apple has achieved with a UInavigationController (also a container view controller): it contains viewController that are happily showing their content, but the navigationController makes sure the navigationBar is always present, for all viewControllers, even during animations.
Apple has some good documentation and even a WWDC session on this.

Hacking your way into [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] is extremely poor design, and a blatant violation of the MVC pattern. It works, but it is a hack nonetheless and might give you headaches in the future.

Comment: The future has arrived. `keyWindow` is deprecated with scene support.

Answer (score 0):

You can add previewView to `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]` as a subview so that it appears on all your views and above each of them.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do this? When I tried 

"[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:_previewVideoView];"

It resulted in 

"exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0xcf99c90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' UIView:0xcf99060.left == UIView:0xcf99300.left + 218> view:<UIView: 0xcf99300; frame = (0 0; 320 416);..."

I've never worked with keywindow before

Comment: It looks like you have an AutoLayout constraint defined for previewView which is causing this error as the constraint needs to be applied to the parent view of all the views that are part of that constraint. Does the autolayout constraint need previewView? If so, you will have to add it to keyWindow or else modify your constraint to no longer refer to previewView.

Comment: Awesome! This worked! All I had to do was take out "autolayout". Do you know if I would need to put the code to control this view (move it around) in the appDelegate? I'm not sure where the code would go to do some actions on this view.